# SPAN vs DIV (inline-block)

Tags: css, html

Is there any reason to use a `<div style="display:inline-block">` instead of a `<span>` to layout a webpage?

Can I put content nested inside the span? What is valid and what isn't?

It's ok to use this to make a 3x2 table like layout?

```
<div>
   <span> content1(divs,p, spans, etc) </span>
   <span> content2(divs,p, spans, etc) </span>
   <span> content3(divs,p, spans, etc) </span>
</div>
<div>
   <span> content4(divs,p, spans, etc) </span>
   <span> content5(divs,p, spans, etc) </span>
   <span> content6(divs,p, spans, etc) </span>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are going for a valid xhtml document then you cannot put block level elements inside of inline elements.

Comment: wiki on html elements http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element

Answer (score 191):

[According to the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4), `<span>` is an inline element and `<div>` is a block element. Now that can be changed using the `display` CSS property but there is one issue: in terms of HTML validation, you can't put block elements inside inline elements so:

```
<p>...<div>foo</div>...</p>
```

is not strictly valid even if you change the `<div>` to `inline` or `inline-block`.

So, if your element is `inline` or `inline-block` use a `<span>`. If it's a `block` level element, use a `<div>`.

Comment: yeah, you can style a span and make it behave just like a div

Comment: I tend to agree that `inline-block` has a closer relationship to `inline` than `block`.

Comment: The original question asked about what is valid, and for validation, `<span>` and `<div>` are indeed different, as `<span>` is an inline element (valid within a `<p>`, for instance), while `<div>` is a block element (not valid within a `<p>`).

Comment: @cletus practically speaking there would be no rendering difference whatsoever in all (the top 5) browsers right?

Comment: @cletus isn't <p> a block element?

Comment: `<p>` is a block element that "cannot contain block-level elements" ([link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-P)), so whilst the example is invalid it is not because `<p>` is inline.

Comment: What if my elements are inline, but one contains sub-elements which need to be block-level relative to sibling sub-elements?

Answer (score 23):

If you want to have a valid xhtml document then you cannot put a div inside of a paragraph.

Also, a div with the property display: inline-block works differently than a span. A span is by default an inline element, you cannot set the width, height, and other properties associated with blocks. On the other hand, an element with the property inline-block will still "flow" with any surrounding text but you may set properties such as width, height, etc. A span with the property display:block will **not** flow in the same way as an inline-block element but will create a carriage return and have default margin.

Note that inline-block is not supported in all browsers. For instance in Firefox 2 and less you must use:

```
display: -moz-inline-stack;
```

which displays slightly different than an inline block element in FF3.

There is a great article [here](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) on creating cross browser inline-block elements.

Comment: -moz-inline-block does inline-block does not.

Comment: If you want it to display more like inline block in FF3 you should actually use inline-stack as well.

Comment: +1 for the very interesting link.  There have been times that inline-block would have solved a number of problems.

Answer (score 6):

1. **Inline-block is a halfway point between setting an element’s display to inline or to block.** It keeps the element in the inline flow of the document like display:inline does, but you can manipulate the element’s box attributes (width, height and vertical margins) like you can with display:block.
2. We must not use block elements within inline elements. This is invalid and there is no reason to do such practices.

Answer (score 3):

I know this Q is old, but why not use all DIVs instead of the SPANs?
Then everything plays all happy together.

Example:

```
<div> 
   <div> content1(divs,p, spans, etc) </div> 
   <div> content2(divs,p, spans, etc) </div> 
   <div> content3(divs,p, spans, etc) </div> 
</div> 
<div> 
   <div> content4(divs,p, spans, etc) </div> 
   <div> content5(divs,p, spans, etc) </div> 
   <div> content6(divs,p, spans, etc) </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think that the goal is to keep everything as lean and semantic as possible. So if you have a header and you want an inner wrapper div - It might <em>seem</em> more semantic to have: header {} and header span {} then It would to have header {} and .inner {}. However... if you use the .inner, you can use it many times - spans would most likely have to be independently styled. Bottom line - you want to use as little markup as possible - so people are trying to figure out ways to avoid div>div>div>div>div etc.

Answer (score 3):

As others have answered… `div` is a “block element” (now redefined as **Flow Content**) and `span` is an “inline element” (**Phrasing Content**). Yes, you may change the default presentation of these elements, but there is a difference between “flow” versus “block”, and “phrasing” versus “inline”.

An element classified as **flow content** can only be used where flow content is expected, and an element classified as **phrasing content** can be used where phrasing content is expected. Since all phrasing content *is* flow content, a phrasing element can also be used anywhere flow content is expected. [The specs provide more detailed info](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#kinds-of-content).

All phrasing elements, such as `strong` and `em`, can *only* contain other phrasing elements: you can’t put a `table` inside a `cite` for instance. *Most* flow content such as `div` and `li` can contain all types of flow content (as well as phrasing content), but there are a few exceptions: `p`, `pre`, and `th` are examples of non-phrasing flow content (“block elements”) that can *only* contain phrasing content (“inline elements”). And of course there are the normal element restrictions such as `dl` and `table` only being allowed to contain certain elements.

While both `div` and `p` are non-phrasing flow content, the `div` can contain other flow content children (including more `div`s and `p`s). On the other hand, `p` may only contain phrasing content children. That means you can’t put a `div` inside a `p`, even though both are non-phrasing flow elements.

Now here’s the kicker. These semantic specifications are unrelated to how the element is displayed. Thus, if you have a `div` inside a `span`, you will get a validation error even if you have `span {display: block;}` and `div {display: inline;}` in your CSS.

Comment: What about inline-block inside inline and block inside inline-block?

Comment: @user764754 as long as you adhere to the specs, you can style any element as you wish and it will still be valid. (`inline-block` is a CSS style, not a type of element or content model.)

Answer (score 3):

I think it will help you to understand the basic differences between Inline-Elements (e.g. span) and Block-Elements (e.g. div), in order to understand why "display: inline-block" is so useful.

**Problem**: inline elements (e.g. span, a, button, input etc.) take "margin" only horizontally (margin-left and margin-right) on, not vertically. Vertical spacing works only on block elements (or if "display:block" is set)

**Solution**: Only through "display: inline-block" will also take the vertical distance (top and bottom). Reason: Inline element Span, behaves now like a block element to the outside, but like an inline element inside

Here Code Examples:

```css
 /* Inlineelement */

        div,
        span {
            margin: 30px;
        }

        span {
            outline: firebrick dotted medium;
            background-color: antiquewhite;
        }

        span.mitDisplayBlock {
            background: #a2a2a2;
            display: block;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }

        span.beispielMargin {
            margin: 20px;
        }

        span.beispielMarginDisplayInlineBlock {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        span.beispielMarginDisplayInline {
            display: inline;
        }

        span.beispielMarginDisplayBlock {
            display: block;
        }

        /* Blockelement */

        div {
            outline: orange dotted medium;
            background-color: deepskyblue;
        }

        .paddingDiv {
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: blanchedalmond;
        }

        .marginDivWrapper {
            background-color: aliceblue;

        }

        .marginDiv {
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: blanchedalmond;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        /* Nur für das w3school Bild */

        #w3_DIV_1 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 391px;
            left: 0px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 913.984px;
            perspective-origin: 456.984px 195.5px;
            transform-origin: 456.984px 195.5px;
            background: rgb(241, 241, 241) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
            border: 2px dashed rgb(187, 187, 187);
            font: normal normal 400 normal 15px / 22.5px Lato, sans-serif;
            padding: 45px;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_1*/

        #w3_DIV_1:before {
            bottom: 349.047px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            content: '"Margin"';
            display: block;
            height: 31px;
            left: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 6.95312px;
            width: 909.984px;
            perspective-origin: 454.984px 15.5px;
            transform-origin: 454.984px 15.5px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 21px / 31.5px Lato, sans-serif;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_1:before*/

        #w3_DIV_2 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: black;
            height: 297px;
            left: 0px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 819.984px;
            column-rule-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            perspective-origin: 409.984px 148.5px;
            transform-origin: 409.984px 148.5px;
            caret-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            background: rgb(76, 175, 80) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
            border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
            font: normal normal 400 normal 15px / 22.5px Lato, sans-serif;
            outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
            padding: 45px;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_2*/

        #w3_DIV_2:before {
            bottom: 258.578px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            content: '"Border"';
            display: block;
            height: 31px;
            left: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 7.42188px;
            width: 819.984px;
            perspective-origin: 409.984px 15.5px;
            transform-origin: 409.984px 15.5px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 21px / 31.5px Lato, sans-serif;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_2:before*/

        #w3_DIV_3 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 207px;
            left: 0px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 729.984px;
            perspective-origin: 364.984px 103.5px;
            transform-origin: 364.984px 103.5px;
            background: rgb(241, 241, 241) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 15px / 22.5px Lato, sans-serif;
            padding: 45px;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_3*/

        #w3_DIV_3:before {
            bottom: 168.344px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            content: '"Padding"';
            display: block;
            height: 31px;
            left: 3.64062px;
            position: absolute;
            right: -3.64062px;
            text-align: center;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 7.65625px;
            width: 729.984px;
            perspective-origin: 364.984px 15.5px;
            transform-origin: 364.984px 15.5px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 21px / 31.5px Lato, sans-serif;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_3:before*/

        #w3_DIV_4 {
            bottom: 0px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            height: 117px;
            left: 0px;
            position: relative;
            right: 0px;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            top: 0px;
            width: 639.984px;
            perspective-origin: 319.984px 58.5px;
            transform-origin: 319.984px 58.5px;
            background: rgb(191, 201, 101) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
            border: 2px dashed rgb(187, 187, 187);
            font: normal normal 400 normal 15px / 22.5px Lato, sans-serif;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_4*/

        #w3_DIV_4:before {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            content: '"Content"';
            display: block;
            height: 73px;
            text-align: center;
            text-size-adjust: 100%;
            width: 595.984px;
            perspective-origin: 297.984px 36.5px;
            transform-origin: 297.984px 36.5px;
            font: normal normal 400 normal 21px / 73.5px Lato, sans-serif;
        }

        /*#w3_DIV_4:before*/
```

```html
   <h1> The Box model - content, padding, border, margin</h1>
    <h2> Inline element - span</h2>
    <span>Info: A span element can not have height and width (not without "display: block"), which means it takes the fixed inline size </span>

    <span class="beispielMargin">
        <b>Problem:</b> inline elements (eg span, a, button, input etc.) take "margin" only vertically (margin-left and margin-right)
        on, not horizontal. Vertical spacing works only on block elements (or if display: block is set) </span>

    <span class="beispielMarginDisplayInlineBlock">
        <b>Solution</b> Only through
        <b> "display: inline-block" </ b> will also take the vertical distance (top and bottom). Reason: Inline element Span,
        behaves now like a block element to the outside, but like an inline element inside</span>

    <span class="beispielMarginDisplayInline">Example: here "display: inline". See the margin with Inspector!</span>

    <span class="beispielMarginDisplayBlock">Example: here "display: block". See the margin with Inspector!</span>

    <span class="beispielMarginDisplayInlineBlock">Example: here "display: inline-block". See the margin with Inspector! </span>

    <span class="mitDisplayBlock">Only with the "Display" -property and "block" -Value in addition, a width and height can be assigned. "span" is then like
        a "div" block element.  </span>

    <h2>Inline-Element - Div</h2>
    <div> A div automatically takes "display: block." </ div>
    <div class = "paddingDiv"> Padding is for padding </ div>

    <div class="marginDivWrapper">
Wrapper encapsulates the example "marginDiv" to clarify the "margin" (distance from inner element "marginDiv" to the text)
        of the outer element "marginDivWrapper". Here 20px;)
        
    <div class = "marginDiv"> margin is for the margins </ div>
        And there, too, 20px;
    </div>

    <h2>w3school sample image </h2>
    source:
    <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp">CSS Box Model</a>
    <div id="w3_DIV_1">
        <div id="w3_DIV_2">
            <div id="w3_DIV_3">
                <div id="w3_DIV_4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```