# Difference between div and span

Tags: html, css

What is the difference between `div` with the property `display:inline-block` and  `span` with `display:inline-block`?

Comment: Insight: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611065/span-vs-div-inline-block

Comment: This is helpful too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is two differences between `div` and `span` elements:

- The `div` has `display:block` as default, while span has `display:inline` as default.
- The `div` is a block element, and can contain block elements and inline elements, while `span` is an inline element and can only contain other inline elements.

Once you have applied the `display:inline-block` they behave the same.

When the HTML code is parsed, the style is not considered. While you can change the `display` style to make the elements behave the same, you still have to follow the rules in the HTML code.

This for example is valid:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

This for example is invalid:

```
<span>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div></div>
</span>
```

The browser will try to rearrange the elements in the invalid code, which usually means that it moves the `div` elements outside the `span` elements. As the HTML specification (prior to version 5) only told how correct code should be handled, each browser has its own way of dealing with incorrect code.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add some historical context to how there came to be `span` vs `div`

History of `span`:

> On July 3, 1995, Benjamin C. W. Sittler **proposes a generic text
> container** tag  for applying styles to certain blocks of text.
> The rendering is neutral except if used in conjunction of a
> stylesheet. There is a debate around  versus  about
> readability, meaning. Bert Bos is mentioning the extensibility nature
> of the  element through the class attribute (with values such as
> city, person, date, etc.). **Paul Prescod is worried that both elements
> will be abused. He is opposed to text mentioning that "any new
> element should be on an old one" and adding "If we create a tag with
> no semantics it can be used anywhere without ever being wrong.** We
> must force authors to properly tag the semantics of their document. We
> must force editor vendors to make that choice explicit in their
> interfaces."

[- Source (w3 wiki)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718121053/https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/span)

From the RFC draft that introduces `span`:

> First, a generic
> container is needed to carry the LANG and BIDI attributes in
> cases where no other element is appropriate; **the SPAN
> element is introduced for that purpose.**

[- Source (IETF Draft)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-html-i18n-01#page-12)

History of `div`:

> CENTER was introduced by Netscape before they added support for the
> HTML 3.0 DIV element. It is retained in HTML 3.2 on account of its
> widespread deployment.

[HTML 3.2 Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/SPSD-html32-20180315/#center)

In a nutshell, both elements arose out of a need for a more generic container that didn't have attached semantics.  Span was proposed as a more generic replacement for a `<text>` element to style text.  Div was proposed as a generic way to divide pages and had the added benefit of replacing the `<center>` tag for center-aligning content.  Div has always been a block element because of its history as a page divider.  Span has always been an inline element because its original purpose was text styling and today div and span have both arrived at being generic elements with default block and inline display properties respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between < div > and < span > si that < span > doesn't have any default styling, where < div > has a paragraph break. 
Hence both tags are extremely similar, applying the css property display:inline-block will have a similar effect, but combined with the vertical-align can have a different effect.

Have a look at this link: http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Comment: A div does not have a break of any kind. You are confusing block level elements that occupy the full width of the browser causing other elements to drop beneath it. A div also does not have any styling. It is a generic container.

Comment: Well, have a look at the official W3 specifications: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4 , find the following text: "Visual user agents generally place a line break before and after DIV elements, for instance...."

Comment: It shows that your comment was not completely true "a div does have a line break". Or W3 is wrong? Anyway, our comments doesn't help answering the main question.

Comment: Nothing in your link suggests a div is styled with a line break except its comments about "most user agents" put one in but that's not part of the spec and, in any case, I would believe is an error in that statement and I will look through the errata and speak to some I know in the W3C.