# What is the difference between div and span?

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between HTML tags DIV and SPAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183532/what-is-the-difference-between-html-tags-div-and-span)
>   [Difference between div and span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047939/difference-between-div-and-span)

Many people are asking me the same question and I don't know the answer. Could you please tell me what is the difference between `div` and `span`; the `html` tags?

**What is the difference?**
**What make them different?**

and some other possible answers you think is better for this. And, please give the `code` which will make `span` work as `div` using `css`

Comment: All elements are the same really, just with different properties. A span behaves just like a div if you set `display: block;` as span is an inline element

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9047939/difference-between-div-and-span

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`div` is a block level element, `span` is an inline element. That's basically the gist of it. ;)

To elaborate; the `div` element's default styling is to be block level. That means it can contain other block level elements as well as in-line elements. The `span` element's default styling is to be in-line, which means block level elements can contain it, but it can't contain block level elements. However, both of these can be altered using CSS, so you could have an inline `div` and a block level `span`!

Bear in mind that although you might be able to get a better content layout by making `span`s block and `div`s inline, if you try to include a block level element inside an element such as `span`, the HTML validator might throw errors at you as *technically* those elements shouldn't be appearing there.

By 'block level' I mean it's a block of content and forces other blocks to appear below it. In-line elements appear within blocks of content, for example, you can add styling to text within a block by using the `span` element, and it won't bring the text 'out of line'.

Answer (score 1):

Span is an inline element, where a div is a block element.

Answer (score 1):

`div` is `display: block` by default. `span` is `display: inline` by default. They may have different elements as their children. They may be children of different elements.

Answer (score 0):

For a start the `div` tag is a block level element and a `span` tag is an inline element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements

Answer (score 0):

A `<span>` is an `inline` element, where a `<div>` is a `block` element.  I see them as basically the same with different default `display` styles.  `<div>` defaults to `display: block` & `<span>` defaults to `display: inline`.

I tend to use `<span>` only then modify the `display` style as needed.

Comment: I was the first answering.  I obviously need to be quicker.