# There's a space inside of a paragraph that's not supposed to be there

Tags: javascript, html, space

I've been having this problem with my html webpage. I have JavaScript to display text when a button is pushed. The problem is, when I run the page it changes the button to the text, but it adds a space between the preloaded text and the inserted text. I am using Notepad++, but I don't think that helps. I'm also using Chrome, which may be the problem but I'm not sure.

The link to the file is here: http://pastebin.com/UqrRguRD

Also the information in there is just random stuff. I'm doing this thing and I needed to make a website, but I'm having this error.

Comment: What steps did you do to try to resolve your problem?

Comment: create a fiddle. Your reference to "main.css" is not useful at all

Comment: Move the closing p tag to be after the word "information", rather than after the div #whatido.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DgEWP/ this?

Comment: Can you not use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Move the closing `</p>` tag and replace `div` elements by `span`, which are displayed `inline` instead of `block` ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1611079/1451422)):

### HTML

```
<span id="whatido"><button onclick="whatIDo()">What do I do?</button></span>
<button onclick="displayResult()">Madlib</button>
<span id="madlib"></span></p>
```

You can also set the `display` property of your buttons to `block` in your css to ensure they're not inline with your text.

### CSS

```
button{
    display:block;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qxRb/1/)

---

## Explanation

`div` elements will not stack horizontally, they have the property `display:block` set by default which makes them take a whole space and clear their sides. To  fix this issue, replace `div` elements by `span` elements. The `span` elements are in `display:inline` by default which makes them line up instead of taking a whole *block* of space

NOTE: [a `div` element is **not considered valid** inside a `p` tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696078/1451422)

---

### W3Schools' definitions

The `<span>` tag is used to group **inline-elements** in a document.

The `<div>` tag defines a **division** or a **section** in an HTML document.

The `<div>` tag is used to group **block-elements** to format them with CSS.

Sources:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

Comment: Can I ask why you replace div with span. What are the differences?

Comment: @JacksonML Take a look at my fresh edit where I explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML it is invalid to place a block level element such as `<div>` inside of a paragraph tag `<p>`. The web browser automatically closes your paragraph tag before `<div id="whatido">` causing the space. One way to fix this is to use `<span>` instead of `<div>` for `#whatido` which is valid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your code

```
<style>
 p {margin: 0px;}
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

or: `p{margin:0;padding:0;}`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hE44e/8/)

Comment: @Ghillied please can you explain me what do you mean by: "it's not valid in html4" and "adds empty p elements everywhere in the code"?

Comment: @Ghillied I flag your comment as uncostructive, not only because you didn't provide an explication about it but also because it is false: if you validate here(http://validator.w3.org/check), for html 4 stict, this code, it will result valid:
**<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<HTML>
   <HEAD>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<style type="text/css">
p{margin:0;padding:0;}
</style>
      <TITLE>My first HTML document</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
      <P>Hello world!</p>
   </BODY>
</HTML>**

Comment: in addition, "<p>" elements are added by the coder, it's senseless saying "the method adds empty p elements everywhere in the code"

Comment: [The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

We discourage authors from using empty P elements. User agents should ignore empty P elements.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1) . The empty `<p>` tags are created by the browser itself since it finds a `block-element` inside the `<p>`. I am still wondering how my comment is not constructive. I sadly can't provide explanations right on time when you ask for them.

Comment: @Ghillied I'm sorry that you provided it late, anyway: 1)giving margin:0 and padding:0 to a <p> element doesn't mean to have an empty <p> element. 2)As the same site from where you provided the infos, it validate the code, probably I suggested a right solution,
3)especially because this code(the code from the question) is not wrong if you try to validate it: "<P>He<button>a</button>llo<span>a</span> world!</p> "
Reassuming: The code that I suggested doesn't 'adds empty p elements everywhere' and it is also valid, so your comment was not right.