# CSS Bottom Margin Issue

Tags: css

I am creating a list with a name, job description, and location. This list contains 30 or so names. I would like the last item-location in the list to have about 20px of margin below to separate the names. So it would look like:

> Name
>  job description
>  location
>
> Name
>  job description
>  location
>
> Name
>  job description
>  location
>
> etc.

I'm also having some issues with text color, but the main issue is the spacing.

[JSFiddle to the below code:](http://jsfiddle.net/art852/GEkP8/)

```
<style> .hed_Brown {
      font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #996633;
      line-height: 18px;
      margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .hed_Green {
      font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #7f9c99;
      line-height: 18px;
      margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .hed_Blue {
      font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #011e41;
      line-height: 18px;
      margin-left: 15px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  </style>

<span class="hed_Brown">Robert Mazzeo</span>
<br> <span class="hed_Green">Load Out Manager</span>
<br> <span class="hed_Blue">Lakeland FL</span>

<br> <span class="hed_Brown">WJ Mahon Jr.</span>
<br> <span class="hed_Green">Sales Manager</span>
<br> <span class="hed_Blue">Jacksonville FL</span>

<br> <span class="hed_Brown">Charles Metzger</span>
<br> <span class="hed_Green">Display Assistant</span>
<br> <span class="hed_Blue">Wichita KS</span>
<br>
```

Comment: I don't see your code

Comment: "Here is my code:" Where ??

Comment: Please include the code in your question instead of a link to a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/art852/GEkP8/

Comment: Although fiddles are very useful, you should really include the code in your question too so it will be useful for others in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/GEkP8/1/

```
.hed_Blue {
  font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #011e41;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
}
```

span elements, are "display: inline" as default, that's why you needed those extra

```
<br>
```

if you declare them "display: block" the problem is solved

Comment: All good solutions, but this one is the fastest for the amount of names I have to edit.thank you

Answer (score 3):

It would be a good idea to use a container for each group. For example:

```
<div class='contact'>
   <span class="hed_Brown">Robert Mazzeo</span>
   <br> <span class="hed_Green">Load Out Manager</span>
   <br> <span class="hed_Blue">Lakeland FL</span>
</div>
```

So you can give the margins you want to `.contact`. In this case, you would probably add:

```
.contact{
   margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Moreover, I would recommend using `<div>` instead of `<span>` and `<br />`, as the `display` propierty of the div already makes the break. Some more info about this here: [SPAN vs DIV (inline-block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611065/span-vs-div-inline-block)

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle, you should remove the `<style>` tags and add the attribute `display: block`: http://jsfiddle.net/GEkP8/2/