# CSS - Why do I need float for my span to show an image with fixed w & h?

Tags: html, css

Look I have this code:
CSS:

```
<style>
span#logo {
    height: 80px;
    width: 222px;
    background: url(img/logo.png);
    /* If I take out this it would give my span 0x0px size */
    float: left;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<span id="logo"></span>
```

Why does it happens? Why do I need to have the float for it to have shape?

Comment: you don't have display: block; is part of it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need float, you need anything to make your `span` not `inline`.  You could (and probably should) just change the `display` to either `block` or `inline-block`.

Comment: It would be inline-block, because with block it gives me a marginal error.

Comment: @ZathrusWriter IE7 does support `inline-block` for spans.

Answer (score 2):

SPAN element itself is dimension-less. It is as big as whatever you put into it. To make it dimensions-aware, you need to change its `display` property to `block` or `inline-block`. Its default display is `inline`, which gives you the behavior you experience.

```
span#logo {
    height: 80px;
    width: 222px;
    background: url(img/logo.png);
    display: block;
    // or: display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Floats are technically block-level elements, but they behave like inline elements in that they often don’t exist on a line of their own — the rest of your content will try to flow around a floated element.

For better understanding [**Read This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611065/span-vs-div-inline-block)