# Is there a way I can adjust the width of a <span> inside a <td>?

Tags: html, css

I have a

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><span style="margin-left: 48px; width: 20px;">2</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

The span seems to have a margin but the width does not work. Is there a way I can make this work? Note that I thought of using a `<div>` but from what I understand it might work but it's not allowed inside a `<td>`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`span` is inline by default. For it to understand the `width` it needs to be at least `inline-block`.

So add the following styles to your css-file:

```css
td span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

P.s. Mind that `display: inline-block;` works from ie8 and higher.

Comment: Beat me to the punch :)  One thing to watch with `inline-block` is that it's not supported on IE8 out-of-the-box.

Comment: @skip405 Why not use a <div> ?

Comment: @Brandon, yep, I thought of adding that to the answer too :)

Comment: @SecretSquirrel, there are various ways of solving the issue ;) We are not sure if we can edit html in this case..

Comment: @skip405 yes I understand that, but I thought it might be worth mentioning that if we are changing the <span> to use inline-block that there are alternative from using a <span> :)

Comment: @SecretSquirrel `span` tags are meant for styling content within other content. `div` has no semantic meaning. Either will work fine in this case, but if the intent is to alter the styling of the content, I would choose a `span` tag.

Comment: Also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611065/span-vs-div-inline-block) as a resource for why use a <span> and not a <div> :)

Comment: @Brandon, you've got a typo in your first comment, surely you meant to say on IE7 :)

Comment: @skip405 It depends on compatibility mode, which makes IE 8 render as if it were IE 7. To get it working consistently, I always add: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` Thanks for "compatibility mode" Microsoft. It's made life so much better for presentation layer developers for years (sarcastically rolls eyes)

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><span style="margin-left: 48px; width: 20px; display: block;">2</span></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Add `display: block;` and then the `<span />` will resize according to the given pixels on the `width` property.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following display property into td.

```
<td>
       <span style="display: table;">Your Content</span>
</td>
```