# columns not displayed horizontally in bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all I should mention that I'm rather new to this.

I'm trying to get my columns to show horizontally, like this:

```
 first column                     second column
```

Instead they are showing like this:

```
 first column
 second column
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8">
             first column
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
             second column
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I replace the `col-md-` with `span` so the div classes are `span8` and `span4` then it works properly. Of course I'm using Bootstrap 3 so I shouldn't be using span but I thought it was interesting to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/cV9Dg/1/)

It is the intended functionality of the grid system to wrap (stack vertically) depending on the viewport (Browser screen-width). For instance, using the `col-md-` class, your columns will be inline (Horizontal) on a 992px or greater viewport. Anything less than 992px, the columns will wrap.

Maybe your monitor or browsers width wasn't greater than 992px while testing your code. IE8 can have the same issue (regardless of viewport) if you are not using `Respond.js` correctly...

If you NEVER want them to wrap try using the `col-xs-` classes. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SchmalzyB/cV9Dg/2/)

Side-Note: `span` elements are `inline` elements and `div` are `block` elements by default, which is why it worked with spans. [See this question for more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611065/span-vs-div-inline-block)

**EDIT:** I misread your question at first (The part about `span` classes)... `span4` classes only exist in bootstrap 2.x, so you must be includeing the wrong version of bootstrap in your project. Check your bootstrap CSS file and make sure you are using the correct version.

Comment: Odd. I see (clearly) that it works in your jsfiddle but I can't get it to work in my code, using exactly the same syntax. Maybe it's because I'm actually the `application.html.erb` layout in Ruby on Rails but still, hmmm. Try as I might I can't get the two columns to appear horizontally.

Comment: @arigold Please see my edit above, you must be using the wrong version of Bootstrap.

Comment: Indeed, it's the wrong version. I had incorrectly assumed that a github repo authored 9 days ago was up to date. Off to find out how to integrate Bootstrap 3 into Rails 4 properly.

Comment: Thanks @Schmalzy that answered it for me.