# How to set a div within text?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to declare CSS for a `div`, so that the declared `div` will be shown inside a line of text? E.g. a `span` can be shown inside text, but how about div? See below or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yCHsF/) for an example.
Thanks in advance

```
This is a * * * Text-Test! * * * 
This is a * * * Text-Test! * <span style="position:absolute; width:200px; color:#FF0000; float:left;"><b>This Span is inside the text or line.</b></span>* * This is a * * * Text-Test! * * *<br/>
This is a * * * Text-Test! * * * This is a * * * Text-Test! * * *<br/>
This is a * * * Text-Test! * <div id="Helper" style="position:absolute; background-color:#00FF00; width:100px; height:20px; float:right;">*** This DIV is at the beginning of the text or line. *** </div>* * This is a * * * Text-Test! * * * <br/>
This is a * * * Text-Test! * * * This is a * * * Text-Test! * * *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display:inline` in css. [Here is the link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5DFF/)

Try like this: `Hello <div style="display:inline;">World!</div> How are you?`

Comment: Yes, but that is not possible if you use that within a paragraph

Comment: `div` inside a paragraph `<p>` tag is invalid according to html standards.

Comment: @user3815508 can I ask to mark my answer as the right answer and an upvote?

Comment: Gladly, but I can't do it, because when I try to it, then I obtain the message: "Vote up requires 15 reputations" , I haven't yet 15-reputations.

Answer (score 2):

As per the following answer, inline div elements should be avoided if possible, as they are not valid. Use span instead.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1611079/2359161

Answer (score 1):

div is a block level element.
Means it always starts and end with new line when displayed in  browser
Also we use divs when we want to give style to group of elements.For Example

```
<html>
<div>
<h1>StackOverflow</h1>
<p>welcome to stackOverflow</p>
</div>
```

Now in above example we group together two html elements.
if you still want to use div as inline block element. You have to do one thing

```
div{
  display:inline;
}
```

Now when you set property to inline it behaves like inline block element.Now your div will accepts margin and padding but it still remain inline.Margin and padding will only push other elements horizontally but not vertically

```
div{
display:inline-block;
}
```

but if you div property to inline-block, then you can set width and height of element and it still remain inline.

for more information
[http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/]