# is it redundant to set width equal to min-width in a span?

Tags: html, css

Maybe a silly question, but I am trying to understand some code that just writes text on screen, on an xhtml document. The text is wrapped with span tags and each word is exactly positioned on the screen using something like:

```
<span id="textID1" style="position:absolute; width:46px; min-width:46px; left:60px; height:22px; min-height:22px; top:90px;" >Hello</span>
```

My question is whether setting width equal to min-width (and also height equal to min-height) is just redundant and I could go with just one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

**1. higher value in min-width:**

```
width: 46px;
min-width: 50px;/*this would be the element width rendered by browser*/
```

**2. higher value in width:**

```
width: 50px; /*this would be the element width rendered by browser*/
min-width: 46px;
```

So, whichever is higher value that would work as the value for the width.

But you have equal value in both width and min-width you can use just width.

And of-course this applies the same for height and min-height.

Comment: you can do the same to height too

Comment: If I just set width and height and the text occupies more than this size, will it be clipped?

Answer (score 1):

Settin `min-width` to the same value as `width` is redundant in the sense that if there are no other style sheets affecting the element, the `min-width` setting has no effect.

But it is not redundant in general. Some other style sheet (in theory, even a user style sheet) may set the `width` property to some other value. In that case, the `min-width` property, when set, prevents the used value of `width` from becoming smaller than the `min-width` value.

Comment: But unless I am wrong, any style sheet that comes at a global level should be overwritten by these inline style settings, isn't it?

Comment: @user1832746, not if they use `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to say but I'll cut short to the straight answer:

> just set width and don't set any of the others.

Short explanation:

A `span` has a default flow of `inline`. Set it with `display: block` or get rid of the span in favor of a `div`. I'd recommend that last choice.

Now, on the `div`, you can set `height` (don't set `min-height`).

On another note: don't set minimum values at all and use CSS classes instead of inline-styling whenever you can.

**EDIT:**

If you need to handle overflowing text better you *MIGHT* want to look into

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

This only works on CSS3 capable browsers!

Comment: OP has absolutely positioned the element meaning that don't need to apply display block...

Comment: Yes I know, but I want him to realize that he really wants a `div`. Using a `span` this way feels like an abuse.

Comment: Actually, setting width to 100% and then setting a min-width is a nice way to make your site scalable quickly... Don't set any others is very.. limiting.

Comment: @pid I want to exactly position each word in a text, for this reason I need to use span(or div) around each one.

Comment: But the idea of span is that you let it *flow* in the text without impeding its development. Those tags have an inherent semantic in HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1611079/3227403

Comment: Thanks @pid reading the answe in the link I see that I need to use span, as I do have all text inside <p> blocks

Comment: Ok, I beg your pardon if I was misleading you :) I had no intention to waste your time.

Comment: No problem @pid, I thank you for your help, I definitely learned something.